# Importing data from Excel into SQL with a Visual Studio Console App

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2014-express

Im working on a project and I need to write a console app that will take data from an Excel file and send it to SQL.  I am new to coding and learning, so I might be missing something, but I have been working on this for two days.  Every instructional site I find doesn't answer the questions.  I have been downloading add-ons, trying it many different ways and I am blown away by now unhelpful (or out-dated) every thing I find is so far!  Is there a way to simply write an app that takes the excel data and imports it into sql express?

I am using Visual Studios 2017, SQL 2014.

Comment: Which ways did you try and how did they fail?

Comment: I have tried remaining the connection string, downloading extensions to communicate with sql, Ive troubleshooted the sql connection, adjusted the tcp/ip service, the sql server in services, I've reinstalled visual studios, installed reporting services, tried creating a console app, a web form, mvc structure, and none of it gets me to the ability to use the app to insert excel data into an sql server.